# Detect which lesson is closest to now

Tags: ios, date, nsdate, uipickerview

I'm having an array with different times of lessons. Here's an example what kind of information my array contains:

09.00 - 10.00, 11.00 - 12.00, 13.00 - 14.00, 15.00 - 16.00

I'm displaying these lessons in a UIPickerView in order to let the user choose the desired time. But I want the PickerView to automatically preselect the lesson which is closest to the actual time. I would somehow have to compare it to the actual date. Has anybody an idea how to do that?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will give the current hour:Minutes

```
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"HH:mm"];
    NSString *str = [dateFormat stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
```

Then you can find the difference and check for minimum.

Now you can put condition like :

```
if      (hh <= 10 )            { // 09:00 - 10:00 should come }
else if (hh == 10 && mm < 30 ) { // 09:00 - 10:00 should come }

else if (hh == 10 && mm > 30 ) { // 11:00 - 12:00 should come }
else if (hh <= 12 && mm < 30 ) { // 11:00 - 12:00 should come }

else if (hh == 14 && mm < 30 ) { // 13:00 - 14:00 should come }
else if (hh <= 14 && mm > 30 ) { // 13:00 - 14:00 should come }

else if (hh == 14 && mm < 30 ) { // 15:00 - 16:00 should come }
else if (hh <= 14 && mm > 30 ) { // 15:00 - 16:00 should come }
else                           { // 15:00 - 16:00 should come }
```